# How to pass composite key as a foreign key

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have tables `CategoryBrand` and `CategoryBrandsubBrand`

In `CategoryBrand` table there is a composite key on (`CategoryId int`, `BrandId int`)

These have to be implement as foreign keys in table `CategoryBrandsubBrand`

`CategoryBrandsubBrand` consist of

- `CategoryBrandId int` (as a foreign key reference to `categorybrand` table)
- `SubBrandId int`

The problem is how to achieve this because if I am creating a foreign key relation it is showing I column at one time as foreign key. Here I need to pass composite key as foreign key

Comment: If you want to add a foreign key reference to a **composite primary key**, then your child table must have **all columns** that make up the composite primary key and make the reference on **all columns** defined in that composite primary key

Comment: Is `CategoryBrandId` the primary key in `CategoryBrand` but the _logical_ key is `(CategoryId int, BrandId int)`?  Or are you expecting to use `CategoryBrandId` as some sort of "concatenated" foreign key?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have this . . .

```
create table CategoryBrand (
  CategoryID int not null,
  BrandID int not null,
  primary key (CategoryID, BrandID)
);
```

then you need something along these lines.

```
create table CategoryBrandsubBrand (
  CategoryID int not null,
  BrandID int not null,
  SubBrandID int not null,
  primary key (CategoryID, BrandID, SubBrandID),
  foreign key (CategoryID, BrandID) 
    references CategoryBrand (CategoryID, BrandID)
);
```

Comment: i want to clear one more thing, now i have to send **CategoryBrandSubBrand** in child table **CategoryBrandSubBrandProduct**
here i have one more column ProductId and the remaing are same and are foreign key reference CategoryBrandSubBrandProduct. the error i am getting is **the column int the table donot match any existing primary key or unique key** how to resolve this